# Jenkins - make agents wait for other agent to finish

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I'm trying to setup a project which will use few build executors.
The flow shall be as follows:

- two build executors with `webservice` label return their IP addresses and wait for the third build executor to finish its job
- third build executor with `tester` label collects those IP addresses and performs some long running job (e.x. sends HTTP requests to the webservices deployed on those two agents)

How to achieve such behavior in Jenkins?

I've found that when an build executor finishes its job it is immediately released and I don't know how to make it wait for other build executors to finish their jobs.

**Edit**:

I forgot to mention that I want the build executors with the `webservice` label to be reserved (not available for other jobs) till the build executor with the `tester` label will finish its long-running job.

Also all these build executors should be on separate slaves each. That means each slave has only one build executor.

Comment: The question wil be easier to understand if you rephrase it using Jenkins terminology (job/project, slave) instead of setting up a "build" that uses "agents".

Comment: Sorry. As I said, I'm new to Jenkins. When I say "agent" I mean build executor (I don't know yet if a build executor and a slave means the the same thing). And I guess "build" shall be changed to "project". Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that's more clear : ) A slave can hold multiple executors (image it as one machine with multiple CPUs for running tasks simultaneously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally managed to do this using [**Pipeline**](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) and below script:

```
node('webservice') {
    def firstHostname = getHostname()
    node('webservice') {
        def secondHostname = getHostname()
        node('tester') {
            println 'Running tests against ' + firstHostname + ' and ' + secondHostname
            // ...
        }
    }
}

def getHostname() {
    sh 'hostname > output'
    readFile('output').trim()
}
```

It acquires two build executors with `webservice` label. I'm getting their hostnames (I'm using them instead of the IP addresses) and pass them to the build executor with a `tester` label. Finally the `tester` runs some long-running tests.

Those two `webservice` build executors are blocked till the `tester` finishes its job, and no other project may use them during that time.

Comment: Nice. So you're using nested pipeline `node` clauses to implement the simultaneous allocation of multiple modes -- good to know that such a thing is possible with the pipeline plugin : )

Comment: Yes. This plugin is very helpful. Maybe the code doesn't look pretty (especially when the number of `webservice` nodes increases), but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

As Alex O mentioned, you can configure the master and slave relationship between the projects /executors inside the Jenkins projects /executors. There is option for that, "Build Triggers" -> Build after other projects are built

or use plugin to achieve it 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

or 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

Comment: I've read about the Join Plugin and also tried it and I've found that I forgot to mention one important thing. I want those two build executors with the `webservice` label to be reserved (not available for other jobs) till the `tester` will finish its job. And it looks like the Join Plugin only gives an option to wait for some jobs to trigger another but the build executors are very quickly moving back to the 'idle' state (just after their simple job is done). I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually *want* is probably that your job uses three slaves at the same time.

Re-thinking the setup in that way, it won't be necessary to consider the collection of IPs and the subsequent usage of the slaves as three different steps that must be aligned in some way.

Unfortunately, Jenkins does not support using multiple slaves for one build out-of-the box, but it will be possible to achieve what you want e.g. using the [Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) and the [Join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) that Aaron mentioned already.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418480/jenkins-job-on-two-slaves) for information on how to use two slaves at the same time.